# Styling Facebook Comment Social Plugin

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I am using Facebook Comment Plugin on a Facebook Tab Page. I want to style the Comments Plugin as per my design. How can I do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty good post that summarizes how to accomplish this. Basically you have to override a number of styles build into the facebook code, but it should all be possible:

http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-the-facebook-comments-social-plugin-on-a-static-fbml-tab/